# Templating outgroups with select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to make all the outgroup labels bold when using select2 and loading the list via an array.  My data looks like this:

```
[{"text":"Brands","children": 
[{"text":"BlackBerry","id":"BlackBerry"}, {"text":"Campagnolo","id":"Campagnolo"},   {"text":"Canon","id":"Canon"},{"text":"FujiFilm","id":"FujiFilm"},{"text":"GoPro","id":"GoPro"},{"text":"Nikon","id":"Nikon"},{"text":"Shimano","id":"Shimano"},{"text":"Vans","id":"Vans"}]}, 

{"text":"Benchmarks","children" 
:[{"id":"powertools","text":"Power Tools"},{"id":"shoes","text":"Shoes"},{"id":"clothing","text":"Clothing"},{"id":"camerasPhoto","text":"Cameras and Photo"},{"id":"healthBeauty","text":"Health and Beauty"},{"id":"electronics","text":"Electronics"},{"id":"homeGarden","text":"Home and Garden"},{"id":"sportingGoods","text":"Sporting Goods"}]}]
```

I don't see how to use the formatState function to select just the outgroup values Brands and Benchmark in this case and format them as bold.